# C# \ Lock \ lock instance member VS lock static member

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

what is better? is there any difference in runtime between the two options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no runtime difference between locking a static and locking an instance member.  However, it can break your code if you use an instance lock and are updating a static.

```
class Broken {
  static int myCounter;
  object synch = new object();

  void SomeMethod()
  {
      lock (synch) { // BAD
        ++myCounter; 
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: so you saying the best practice is to lock static object in class?

Comment: I have always used a static for locking purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Huh? I thought it should depend on what you are locking for. If you are trying to lock a non-static object, it should be locking non-static object. By the way, you might want to investigate on what you are trying to do, most of the time, there are already thread safe objects built-in language.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you locking a non-static method ? You typically only need synchronization around access to a shared resource, i.e. one that will be shared among all threads. You wouldn't do this with an instance method, you'd want a singleton.